# How to connect to the Wordpress instance (API) created using Azure Marketplace from .NET/C# code?

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have created an Azure AppService using Azure Marketplace item for Wordpress. Is there any way to connect this Wordpress instance from C# code? If yes - how?

Comment: You are not very clear what you are trying to achieve. But WordPress does have a [rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)